# log4j2 singleton custom appender using @PluginFactory

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I have written a custom Appender using log4j2. Is there any simple way I can make it singleton ? I am using @Plugin and @PluginFactory.

Actually this is the problem which I am running into (and yes looks like making it singleton is not a solution). I created a custom appender using the following code

```
MyAppender myAppender =  MyAppender.createAppender(MyAppender.MY_APPENDER_NAME);
final LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
final Configuration config = loggerContext.getConfiguration();
myAppender.start();
config.addAppender(myAppender);
AppenderRef[] refs = new AppenderRef[] { AppenderRef.createAppenderRef(MyAppender.MY_APPENDER_NAME, null, null) };
LoggerConfig loggerConfig = LoggerConfig.createLogger("false", Level.DEBUG, Logger.getRootLogger().getName(), "true", refs, null, config, null);
loggerConfig.addAppender(myAppender, Level.DEBUG, null);
config.addLogger(Logger.getRootLogger().getName(), loggerConfig);
ctx.updateLoggers();
return myAppender;
```

My appender has another method xyz(). When I try to call xyz using the following code, it instead calls the append method of appender. This is very surprising and I have no clues why this is happening.

```
myAppender = (MyAppender) Logger.getRootLogger().getAppender(MyAppender.MY_APPENDER_NAME);
myAppender.xyz()
```

Also, when I create another instance of appender, instead of fetching it using getAppender, it works fine. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could create a single instance, cache it in a static final field, and return that instance from the @PluginFactory annotated factory method.

That assumes you want to explicitly prevent users to modify parameters for your appender when the configuration is modified, is that your motivation for making this a singleton?

Comment: Thanks a lot lot, Remko. I have updated the question. Kindly have a look. I don't think singleton is the solution. I think the way I am accessing it or creating it is wrong.